# How to create regular expression pattern for AWS bucket name

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Following are the conditions which should match:

1)The bucket name can be between 3 and 63 characters long, and can contain only lower-case characters, numbers, periods, and dashes.

2)Each label in the bucket name must start with a lowercase letter or number.

3)The bucket name cannot contain underscores, end with a dash, have consecutive periods, or use dashes adjacent to periods.

4)The bucket name cannot be formatted as an IP address (198.51.100.24).

Comment: Can you provide test strings for those `rules`, it may be difficult to do all this with one Regx, can you use multiple checks etc.  Need more info to answer.

Comment: I hate linking to other resources, but I'd suggest [this could be used](http://info.easydynamics.com/blog/aws-s3-bucket-name-validation-regex) to add an answer to this question

Comment: Hi ArtisticPhoenix, you can take any string which should satisfy all above conditions.

Comment: Ganesh Jagtap, what did you try yourself ? Other then letting us do the work for you - more then happy to help improve what you have.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Scuzzy.